# Windsurfing in Switzerland (or nearby areas)

Tags: switzerland, zurich, water-sports

What are the recommendations, options, possibilities for windsurfing in Switzerland?

I'm especially interested in Zurich and places with nice transport connections.

Feel free to write about Windsurfing or recommendations in other areas, as I'd love to make this question as valuable as possible for other Tr.SE users.

Comment: Isn't windsurfing recommendations in other areas a little bit too broad? Basically, the answer to this question is a list with all places over the world where you can windsurf. I would like the first part of your question (focus on Zurich) much more.

Comment: Windsurfing Lake of Uri is best place

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a platform for recommendations. But I think answering is possibly based on a trade-off of how well-regarded a place is for windsurfing vs how close it is to Zurich. This should make the list very small and keep subjectivity to a minimum./

Answer (score 9):

[Here you will find a map](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=de&ie=UTF8&msa=0&msid=108857510789096848264.000463b07040c7bc82e47&t=p&ll=45.637087,7.800293&spn=4.993142,5.438232&z=7&source=embed) of all windsurfing schools that are part of the Swiss Windsurf Organisation. This will provide you with a good overview about the spots where wind surfing is possible in Switzerland, and will also give you a staring point if you need some instructions in the beginning.

Here the interactive map as an image:

[image]

[Here you will find an interactive map](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=de&msa=0&msid=108857510789096848264.000467e4ded120b5f1de9&t=p&ll=46.777493,8.580322&spn=3.385777,5.438232&z=7&source=embed) of all wind surfing clubs in Zurich. This will also provide you a good starting point.

Personally, I know the spot at [Tiefenwinkel bei Mühlehorn, Walensee](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Tiefenwinkel%20bei%20M%C3%BChlehorn,%20Walensee&hl=de&ie=UTF8&sll=47.113481,9.189291&sspn=0.033295,0.093513&t=p&hnear=Tiefenwinkel,%208877%20M%C3%BChlehorn,%20Glarus,%20Schweiz&z=15&iwloc=A) which is the official place of the Liechtenstein Windsurfing Club. Every time I'm there, there are some people windsurfing, because the Walensee is located between two big mountains and therefore it is a very cold lake (actually the coldest lake in Switzerland) and it is almost always windy there.

It is also relatively close to Zurich. By car you will be there in 40 minutes and by public transport in approximately 57 minutes:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am not a windsurfing specialist, but I can see many people doing it on all the lakes I pass by.

Mainly there are the Bielersee, Murtensee and Lac de Neuchatel (Neuenburgsee in German) these are in the region of the three lakes.

Lake Geneva is also very popular especially when the east wind is blowing (a strong wind called *bise* in French).

I haven't often been to Zurich but I am sure there are possibilities to indulge in this sport on Lake Zurich.

It depends what you are looking for, but with so many lakes, Switzerland is definitively a good country for windsurfing, wherever you are.

Answer (score 3):

You will find some very good places at the **IJseelmeer** in Holland. **Lake Garda** in Trentino, Italy, is another famous spot with thermal wind that starts blowing usually around 12am. The area you might be most interested in is the northern one, near Riva or Limone or Torbole. You will find people rushing around 11am even if there is no single movement of the air :)

Comment: I added a bit of information about Lake Garda and its locations; however, I feel that this answer is not particularly relevant to the question as it does not address the main part, which is about Switzerland.